# React-Router Webpack exclude server logic from bundling to client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I am making an isomorphic react application, but now I am stuck of figuring out how to exclude server-side logic from bundling into client side javascript using react-router and webpack.

So my webpack has an entry points to **"client.js"** which is the clientside bundle javascript.

```
import React from "react";   import Router from "react-router";  
import routes from "../shared/routes";

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (Handler, state) => {  
React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('react-app')); });
```

**"client.js"** contains react-router routes definition.

And for the server side, I have epxress and route set up as * (all requests route to here)

**"server.js"**

```
import routes from "../shared/routes";

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {   
    Router.run(routes, req.url, (Handler, state) => {
        let html = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
        res.render('index', { html: html });     
    }); 
});
```

Since both client and server share the same routes, if I want to set up a route in the react-router e.g. /attractions/:id that will contain server side logic (database query, etc), it will get bundled by the webpack to the client.js

So I am wondering if there is a way to keep just one routes.js that shared by both **"client.js"** and **"server.js"** and have **"client.js"** not bundle some of the server routes.

I came up few possible solutions. But would like to see the best way to do it.

1. Keep two routes, one for server and one for client, and server routes is the superset of client routes.
2. Add another layer of abstraction to react-router, so instead of

`<Route handler="/attraction/:id"/>`

I can use import ABC from "ABCRouteController" and ABCRouteController will determine whether it's node or client and generate route or not generate route.

```
class AppController extends React.Component {

    render () {

        let route;

        if #isServer
            route = <Route handler={#someHandler}" path="/">
        else
            route =""

        return route;
    }
}
```

3. Add specific routing to server.js. So instead of

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) { 
    Router.run(routes, req.url, (Handler, state) => {
            let html = React.renderToString();
            res.render('index', { html: html });
    });
});
```

We add more specific routing for handling pure server side logic (similar to two seperate react-router for server and client)